# HashMap Java get value if it exists

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap

I wish to get a value from a HasMap but some time the value doesn't exist so I have done this:

```
int var = 0;
if (hashMapHouse.containsKey("home1") {
    var = hashMapHouse.get("houme1");
}
if(var==0) //do something
else //do something else
```

My question is: is it possible to have one call of hashMap in order to get the value and to test if the value exist or no?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Java 8 you can use the [getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method:

```
int var = hashMapHouse.getOrDefault("home1", 0);
```

It's the cleanest solution, in a single line you can get either the value for the key if it exists, or a predefined default value to indicate that it doesn't exist - `0` in this case.

Comment: If the value of the HashMap is not a `int` but an object is a similar way to do it (`int var = hashMapHouse.getOrDefault("home1", 0);`)?

Comment: Yes, why don't you test it?

Answer (score 2):

Sure

```
Integer houme = hashMapHouse.get("houme1");

if (null == houme ) {
    // not exists 
} else {
    // exists 
}
```

Comment: But I wish to have also the value of the hashMapHouse

Comment: HashMap can allow null values, so checking for null value doesn't guarantee key doesn't exist.

Comment: @getITdone Well, in OP case, `int` cant be value in HashMap anyway

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-):

> A return value of null does not necessarily indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to null. The containsKey operation may be used to distinguish these two cases.

If you are not using `null` as value then you can use the `get()` method once and do it like this:

```
Integer var = hashMap.get(key);
if (var != null) {
    // value exists
}
```

Comment: Who *(provide link, please)* is "not recommending" the method, and what do they recommend instead? Given that most recommendations are to not store `null` in a Map (especially since some maps don't even allow it), why would it not be recommended to rely on `get()` returning `null` as meaning "not found", since it outperforms having to call `containsKey()` first?

Comment: @Andreas We can explicitly keep `null` against a `key` in a `Map`. So if that's the case for OP, then it would not be a good idea to use just `get()` to determine if `key-value` exists or not. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: *If* the Map *will* contain null values, calling `get()` will not be able to distinguish "missing" from "there with null". If you need to know the difference, then yes, you'll need to call `containsKey()`. Most of the time, a Map will not contain null values *(especially guaranteed when using Maps that won't allow it)*, so there is no ambiguity in those cases. --- But that's beside the point. You said *"this is not **the** recommended method"*, and I was asking you **who** made that recommendation, because I haven't seen/heard it before.

Comment: @Andreas Okay, I agree I gave my opinion without backing it up. I'll remove it

Comment: It's ok to give your opinion, but you should phrase it so people will know it's *your* opinion. You had phrased it as being a generally accepted recommendation. Instead, you could have said "But I wouldn't recommend it because ...", or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to fetch the value while checking the condition, to avoid accessing the HashMap twice.

```
if ((temp = hashMapHouse.get("home1") != null) {
    var = temp;
}
```

temp variable are set in the same time we verify our condition.